# Insert a duplicate record based on value of another column

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I have a db table named `Student`, with columns as `id`, `name`, `age`. 
`id` is the Primary Key, `name` is not null, and `age` can be null

I want to implement the following in php, Zend:
**Only add a duplicate student `name` in db if the `age` value is different.**

Inside the function/action `addStudentAction`, I am calling the Student model's function -`findStudent` to implement the requirement:

```
public function findStudent($name)
{
    $result = null;

    $select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->where('student.name = ?', $name);

    //error_log($select->assemble());

    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchRow($select);

    return $result;
}

public function addStudentAction() {
    $data = $_POST;
    $studentModel = new Application_Model_Student;
    $result = $studentModel->findStudent($data['name']);

    if(!empty($result)) { 
        error_log("found student name in db, going to get age");

       //Check for age
       if( (!empty($result['age'] )) {
             if( $result['age'] != $data['age']) {
                  error_log("going to add student as new record");
                  return $this->insert($data);
             }
             else {
                  error_log("not adding new student record ");
             }
       }
    }
}
```

Now, **there could be multiple records of Students with same `name` but different `age` values.** Therefore, when adding a new student, I need to compare the ages of all records(if name matches) with the incoming value of age.

What could be best way to implement this requirement? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a compound UNIQUE index on the name, then age field. UNIQUE allows multiple NULL values, so that won't be an issue. Depending on your database size and usage, this might not be the most preferred option, in which case a simple SELECT of the student information before an INSERT to check if he/ she is already in there would be the best solution.

Let me know if I need to elaborate on this. I'd be happy to give you some examples.

Comment: This would have been a good option but I cannot apply indexes right now. Therefore was looking for something on code side.

Comment: Why are you not able to add an index? Either way, a SELECT query for the data before INSERT would be your best bet than.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do a new SELECT with name and age:

```
public function findStudentWithAge($name, $age =null)
{
    $result = null;

    $select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->where('student.name = ?', $name);
    if($age) $select->where('student.age = ?', $age);

    //error_log($select->assemble());

    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchRow($select);

    return $result;
}
```

Now in the addStudentAction:

```
public function addStudentAction() {
    $data = $_POST;
    $studentModel = new Application_Model_Student;
    $result = $studentModel->findStudent($data['name'], $data['age']);

    if(!empty($result)) { 
        error_log("found student with this age, cannot add the record");
    } else {
        $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, there is another condition I have that this solution would not satisfy - **I do not want names with different cases added to the db**. Eg If John already exists in db, I do not want the new record being added as john or joHn or any other such versions. Therefore, I want to check the `name` separately and if that matches then check for `age`. If `age` is different then add record in db and send the value of `name` from existing `name`record.

Comment: Therefore, before I call the `$this->insert($data)`, I will be overwriting the `name` in the `$data` array to the value from the db. ie. `$data['name'] = $result['name']; $this->insert($data);`